# Passing form data to express

Tags: reactjs, forms, express, post, axios

Having a tough time passing some data to express. I am trying to send some data I gather from a form. The form value is being updated correctly. But when I hit my end point I do not know how to log out what I am passing. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

**Express:**

```
app.post('/something-to-post', cors(corsOptionsDelegate), (req, res)=> {
 //how do I log what I am passing from the form 
  console.log('full name:', req.data);
});
```

**React**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setFullName(event.target.value); // updates state properly
  }

  function post(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('full name:', fullName); // logs out correctly
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/something-to-post', {name: fullName})
      .then(response => {
        // todo
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // todo
      })
   }
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={post}>
    <input type="text" value={fullName} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  )
 };

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this code below:

**FrontEnd:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form  = () => {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setFullName(event.target.value); // updates state properly
  }

  function post(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('full name:', fullName); // logs out correctly
    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/something-to-post', {name: fullName})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.data)
      })
   }
  return ( 
    <form onSubmit={post}>
    <input type="text" value={fullName} onChange={handleInputChange}/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
   );
}

export default Form;
```

**Backend:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/something-to-post', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.name);
  const response = {
    success: true,
    code: 200,
    message: 'Data from backend',
    data: req.body
  }
  res.status(200).send(response);
})

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I needed to install and utilize npm i body-parser for req.body.name to work for me.

Comment: If you're using the latests version of express, then you should not to install body parser. You can use express. That code above it's an example that you've not needed to install body-parser.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do this the react way which is keep track of data in the state.

First Add a function to update the data `handleInputChange`. Then add a name attribute to the input which value you need to update. Check the below and read more about [React forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {
  // Set initial state 
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({fullName: ''})

  // Add a function to update the value of your input fields
  handleInputChange(event) {
     const target = event.target;
     const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
     const name = target.name;

     setValues({ ...values, [name]: value })
  }

  function post(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = document.getElementById('full-name').value;

    let data = {
      name: values.fullName, // get the value of the input field from the state
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:9000/something-to-post', data)
      .then(response => {
        // todo
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // todo
      })
   }
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={post}>
    <input id="fullName" name="fullName" type="text" value={values.fullName} onChange={(evt)=>this.handleInputChange(evt)} />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  )
 };

export default Form;
```

Comment: I updated the code to use state and added a handler to handle the input change, form is working properly. In express I don't know how to log out what I am capturing from the form

Comment: You need to install `body-parser` and use it. Read more about it here https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Comment: has my solution been helpful?